# SVN name conflicts and multiple versions

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, svn

I have a C++ project developed under both Windows (VS2010) and Linux (Eclipse). The non-portable portion of the source is isolated in one non-portable file (NonPortable.cpp). I would like to use SVN to manage the source. Everything works, I can check-in/out/commit from both Windows and Linux, but I don't know how to handle that NonPortable.cpp file. Is there a way to keep both versions and tell the SVN to work with the appropriate one?

I've been using Subversive SVN in Eclipse and VisualSVN in VS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

NonPortable.cpp file should have all the code of all the compilers for all the OS'es, and everything should be organized with predefined macros. Each compiler defines a set of macros to deal with such situations. For VS2010 check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) and macros such as _WIN32 and _MSC_VER.